# How do I return the result of a recursive fetch?

Tags: asynchronous, recursion, fetch

I have the first asynchronous function

```
fetch("https://api.priceapi.com/v2/jobs", {
            body: body,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            },
            method: "POST"
                }).then((response) => {
                            return response.json();
                        }).then((data) => {

                            return fetchRepeat(data.job_id)
                        })
```

And the second recursive asynchronous function.

```
function fetchRepeat(id){

    fetch("https://api.priceapi.com/v2/jobs/"+ id +"/download.json?token=" + priceapisecret.secret)
    .then((response) => {
        return response.json()
    }).then((data) =>{
        if(data.status == "finished"){

            var bookdata = {
                title: data.results[0].content.name,
                price: data.results[0].content.price
            }

            return bookdata;

        }
        else{
            fetchRepeat(id)
        }
    })
}
```

I want to be able to access bookdata in the first async function. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to talk about a return your `fetchRepeat` needs to return the promise. It did not so returning `undefined` was the result. The last `then` also didn't return the value of the recursion and thus also resolved to `undefined`.

Here is a working version:

```js
function fetchRepeat(id) {
    // return the promise
    return fetch(`https://api.priceapi.com/v2/jobs/${id}/download.json?token=${priceapisecret.secret}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(({ status, results: [{ content: { name: title, price } }] = [{ content: {} }] }) =>
            (status === 'finished' ? { title, price } : fetchRepeat(id))); // return result of recursion
}
```

Now I let ESLint handle the formatting and since I use airbnb it prefers destructuring. The error in the last `then` was obvious since ELSint complained about consistent return. I urge you to use a linter and an IDE which enforces a coding style to reduce bugs in your code and make it easier for others to read.

Comment: according to the OP, your destructuring needs to get a little messier before the job is done: `.then(({ status, results: [ { content: { name: title, price } = {} ] = [] }) => ...`

Comment: @user633183 Fixed. Thanks :)